# Does pytables support NULL?

Tags: python, database

I have table looks like this

```
------------------ 
GeneId | ProteinId
1      |    157 
2      |     - 
3      |    587     
4      |    897 
5      |     - 
6      |    120
```

In realational database, I can treat ProteinId column as INT and use NULL for "-" data. However, I can't find the same option in pytables. Does pytables support NULL ? Currently, I use "0" for NULL data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [the docs](http://www.pytables.org/moin/HintsForSQLUsers) say,

> Cells in a PyTables' table always have
>   a value of the cell type, so there is
>   no NULL. Instead, cells take a default
>   value (zero or empty) which can be
>   changed in the type declaration, like
>   this: col_name = StringCol(10,
>   dflt='nothing') (col_name takes the
>   value 'nothing' if unset).

So, for integer columns, a default of 0 is normally used, and, no, alas!, there is no way to mark a value as missing or unknown, as NULL does in SQL.